# error on fetching api in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am fetching api using api key and data from input box , I am getting
error array that query must be provided. I am able to get data from
inputbox. Below is the code.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = { movie: '', movieList: [] };
    this.onGetMovie = this.onGetMovie.bind(this);
  }

  onGetMovie(data) {
    this.setState({ movie: data });
    console.log("--------");
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("*************");
    fetch('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?query=' + this.state.movie + '&api_key='+API_KEY)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(movieList => {
        this.setState({ movieList: movieList.results });
        console.log(movieList);
      })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={icons} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">
            Movies<span className="secondary">Db</span>
          </h1>
        </header>

        <SearchBar handleToParent={this.onGetMovie} />
        <p>Parent : {this.state.movie}</p>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Can you show us the exact error? Or it's somehow confidential?

Comment: it is asking for `query` as you are not setting it as your fetchApi is being called in the `componentDidMount()`  will be called right after the component have been rendered please take a look at the [componentDidMount()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) docs.

Comment: {errors: Array(1)}
errors
:
["query must be provided"]
__proto__
:
Object

Comment: GET https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?query=&api_key=194frc5f3776ef506231a4bg2053fc62 422 ()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`movie` located in component's state is not available yet for `componentDidMount`.

`fetch` should be invoked after `onGetMovie` is called (even by `onGetMovie` method) and you'll get all data required to perform the query.

Comment: I inserted fetch inside onGetMovie() still i get same error

Comment: @AbhishekKonnur Do you still refer to `this.state.movie` ?

Comment: onGetMovie(data) {
    this.setState({ movie: data });
    fetch('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?query=' + this.state.movie + '&api_key='+API_KEY)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(movieList => {
      this.setState({ movieList: movieList.results });
      console.log(movieList);
    })
  }

Comment: `state` is not populated synchronously, so you can't access it right after calling `setState`. Simply use `data` variable in your query URL.

Comment: Now I am able to fetch after using data in link